# How to get dates from PHP and MySQL database that is equal to the current date?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

In my table, I have a field called `created_at` with data type `timestamp` and values are like `2016-12-30 00:30:10` and so on.

In my query, I get all those by a simple `select *` statement.

How can I get only the dates where it is equal to today's date?

I am using a framework called [makoframework](http://makoframework.com) and the query builder is this:

```
$data = $query->table('customers')
->where('created_at', '=', //date today)
->all();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use DATE(created_at) hope it will work.

Comment: It says DATE(created_at) column is not found @SoniyaReddy

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
->where('DATE(created_at)', '=', '2016-12-30')
```

I'm sure about the query but I haven't used that framework so i'm not sure if it will pass it over to mysql as it is.

Use this for your framework

```
->whereRaw('DATE(created_at)', '=', '2016-12-30')
```

Comment: 'DATE(created_at)' is counted as a column

Comment: That's fine mysql will know what to do with it

Comment: I get this Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Date(ph.created_at)' in 'where clause'

Comment: That most probably means the framework is sending that parameter in quotes. Use the raw query option and it will work like a charm

Answer (score 2):

This will work

WHERE DATE(`created_at`) = CURDATE()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which framework you are using but in Core PHP you can use date() function to print the current date in a specific format.

```
 $data = $query->table('customers')
         ->where('DATE(created_at)', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
         ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

So I opened an issue in the framework's github site and the correct way to which is working is this:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d');
->where(new Raw('Date(ph.created_at)'), '=', $now)
```

Just remember to import `mako\database\query\Raw`

Thanks for all the help.